# Contract deploy issue

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

Can someone take a look the issue below and help me understand the reason of this issue?

Ethereum Go returns the following error when I trying deploy my contract into dev network using loadScript function:

> loadScript("file.js")
>   null [object Object]
>   true
>   Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined

The file contains:

```
var first_sol_firstContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"close","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_bets","type":"uint256[3]"}],"name":"play","outputs":[{"name":"_resultCode","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_valuePayout","type":"uint256"}],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"hand","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"hand_value","outputs":[{"name":"_total","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var first_sol_first = first_sol_firstContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Thank you!
L. Alex

Comment: Did you try increasing gas?

Comment: Prashant, Thank you for the response. Yes, I tried increasing gas limit, but it doesn't help. When I reduce size of data the contract deploying successfully. Are there limits for the size of contract?

Comment: Oh yeah, you have supplied more than enough gas. Every block has a has limit which can't be exceeded. If your transaction exceeds the block gas limit, it is not contained in any of the blocks and hence you were unable to deploy contract.

Answer (score 1):

The possible issue could be the gasLimit. Ethereum limits the number of tx that can be put in a block using gasLimit. So check if the gas you need to deploy contract is more than the gasLimit for the block.

Comment: _Ethereum limits the number of tx that can be put in a block using gasLimit._ - Can you specify these limits? Thank you!

Comment: you can find the limit by using `eth.getBlock('latest').gasLimit`. This is the maximum gas that all transactions included in the block together can use. So if your contract tries to consume more than this gasLimit to deploy then it will not be deployed.